# Can't import name "Dispatcher" from telegram.ext

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am a beginner with python-telegram-bot, I have installed version 20.0.

I installed a package "django-telegram bot" to help me integrate python-telegram-bot into django but I got an import error upon running the code

`ImportError: cannot import name "Dispatcher" from telegram.ext`

I delved into the python-telegram-bot package and discovered that there is no module called Dispatcher, but several online tutorials directly imported Dispatcher from telegram.ext.

Answer (score 2):

The `django-telegram-bot` library is just not compatible with version 20 of `python-telegram-bot`. As you can see in the [requirements file](https://github.com/jlmadurga/django-telegram-bot/blob/master/requirements/base.txt) it requires the ancient version 5.3.0 of `python-telegram-bot` (it was released on [2016-12-11](https://pypi.org/project/python-telegram-bot/5.3.0/)).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Answer (score 0):

To import the dispatcher module, you'll first need to install the python-telegram-bot package. It looks like, from the question you have done this.

```
pip install python-telegram-bot
```

then all you have to do is this:

```py
from telegram import Dispatcher
```

it is not imported from `telegram.ext`. from what i can see the `telegram.ext` part looks like this.

```py
from telegram.ext import MessageHandler, Filters

def handle_message(bot, update):
    message = update.message.text
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text=message)

dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, handle_message))
```

and that reqires a bot which is derived from this:

```py
from telegram import Bot
bot = Bot(token="YOUR_BOT_TOKEN")
```

Which is different to what is suggested in the original question.